# KnockoutJS get property value

Tags: knockout.js

I have a really simple question, but can't understand what I am missing.
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var viewModel = {
    test: ko.observable(null)
}
var obj = {
    name: "name123"
}
viewModel.test(obj);    
ko.applyBindings(viewModel.test, document.getElementById("a"));
alert(viewModel.test.name());
});​
```

link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwkAB/
Why I can't get the name property value?

UPDATE:
It should be 
    viewModel.test().name

Comment: The fiddle seems to work just fine, or...?

Comment: the alert is not working with me. In mozilla it says: "TypeError: viewModel.test.name is not a function"

Comment: @WernerVesterås the alert was not working because user1025981 had not made the property of the child object observable, however was calling the member 'name' as a method as though it was observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwkAB/2/), You need to make the child objects property observable in order to bind to it. As well as adding the with binding to help with scope in the HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewModel = {
        test: ko.observable(null)
    }
    var obj = {
        name: ko.observable("name123")
    }
    viewModel.test(obj);    
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    alert(viewModel.test().name());
});​
```

Comment: without the parenthesis on name is working as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @user1025981 please check the new jsfiddle for a good example of how to simplify the info, taking off the parenthesis and leaving the property as static instead of observable is an option but i think you will prefer the new example, also note the HTML 'with:' binding

Comment: I understand, but the situation is the following:
I make ajax request and get an array of objects. I create a listview in a mobile application with this array. I wire up a click event for the list items and when a list item is clicked I save it in an object - selectedItem and make a transition to a details view page. Then I bind the details page for this selected item. But the properties of the selected items are not observable, because they come from the request.. Is there anything that i can do for these properties?

Comment: I think i should use ko.mapping, i totally have missed that concept of the framework.

Comment: @user1025981 that is certainly an option, but do some benchmarking and you will find that the slowest part of using knockout is where the mapping is used.  it certainly saves you a few lines of code, but whats a few lines of code when compared to user experiance.  Just a little friendly advice.